# takePicture in a native glass app doesn't produce any output

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm building a native app for glass. I want to access the camera. The preview works fine (preview and previewcallback) but when it comes to take picture using the glass the program just continue and when you check the output no picture was taken (it doesn't event enter in any of the callbacks (Shutter, PictureRaw, PictureJpg).

I also tried using the intent method and the Media.Image_Capture. It just return a null pointer. (or an empty file if you specify a file)

Does any of you have an idea why ?  And if you know any workaround ?

Thanks

best,

Comment: Can you please put some code?
I have built a native camera and it is working well in my glass.Only problem is the glass did not support auto focus so I have to remove the auto focus functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version XE8 on the Glass OS fixe the issue.

Best,